# How to get Average hits between current date to posted date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

Hi have a table name `images`

**images**

```
id        hits       created
--------------------------------------
1         10       2014-11-07 11:07:57
2         8        2014-11-10 05:10:20
3         70       2014-10-04 08:04:22
```

In above table i want to get the average highest number of Frequency record.

```
Q. What is Frequency?
A. Frequency means number-of-hits/number-of-days(current date - created date)
```

N.B- days you will get to current-date minus created-date.

**Example:-** Suppose my hits is `10` and created date is `2014-11-07 11:07:57` then the Frequency will be `10/4=2.5` Same as `8/1=8` and `70/37=1.89`

I need to get all records order by Frequency descending in a single MySQL query.

Thanks
chinu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATEDIFF` function.

### Query

```
SELECT id,hits,created,
hits/(DATEDIFF(NOW(),created)) AS Frequency
FROM images
ORDER BY Frequency DESC;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+---------------------------------+-----------+
| ID | HITS |         CREATED                 | FREQUENCY |
|----+------+---------------------------------+-----------+
|  2 |    8 | November, 10 2014 05:10:20+0000 |   8       |
|  1 |   10 | November, 07 2014 11:07:57+0000 |   2.5     |
|  3 |   70 |  October, 04 2014 08:04:22+0000 |   1.8421  |
+----+------+---------------------------------+-----------+
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94765/2)

Comment: @chatfun:Welcome. Please mark it as answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Do you know CakePHP? please answer my question. I am getting another problem Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859700/cakephp-order-not-working

Answer (score 0):

For more precision using hour you also can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

```
SELECT id,hits,created,
hits/((TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,created,NOW()))/24) AS Frequency
FROM images
ORDER BY Frequency DESC;
```