# CakePHP order not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hi i am using CakePHP version - 2.5.5.

I have a table name `chat_ategory_mages` I want to get Average number of Frequency Order by Descending. Know about the Frequency please check - [How to get Average hits between current date to posted date in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858108/how-to-get-average-hits-between-current-date-to-posted-date-in-mysql)

**chat_ategory_mages**

```
id        chat_category_id    hits       created
------------------------------------------------
1         5                  10       2014-11-07 11:07:57
2         5                  8        2014-11-10 05:10:20
3         5                  70       2014-10-04 08:04:22
```

**Code**

```
$order=array('Frequency' => 'DESC');
$fields=array(
    'ChatCategoryImage.id',
    'ChatCategoryImage.chat_category_id',
    'ChatCategoryImage.created',
    'ChatCategoryImage.hits',
    'hits/(DATEDIFF(NOW(),created)) AS Frequency',
);
```

*QUERY-1*

```
$rndQry=$this->ChatCategoryImage->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('ChatCategoryImage.chat_category_id'=>$cetegory_id), 'fields'=>$fields, 'order'=>$order, 'limit'=>10));
pr($rndQry); //WORKING FINE
```

*QUERY-2*

```
//THIS IS NOT WORKING
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'conditions'=>array('ChatCategoryImage.chat_category_id'=>$cetegory_id),
        'fields'=>$fields,
        'limit' => 10,
        'order' => $order,
);
$getCategoryImages = $this->Paginator->paginate('ChatCategoryImage');
pr($getCategoryImages); //NOT WORKING
```

Above table if i write simple cakephp query the `order` is working fine but when i am using cakephp pagination it is not working. If i am using `$order=array('hits' => 'DESC');` this its woring perfect. Showing result 70,10,8 consistently but when i am adding `Frequency` it the result not coming the descending order.

**Mysql Query**

QUERY-1 :

SELECT `ChatCategoryImage`.`id`, `ChatCategoryImage`.`chat_category_id`,  `ChatCategoryImage`.`hits`, `ChatCategoryImage`.`created`, hits/(DATEDIFF(NOW(),created)) AS Frequency, FROM `myshowcam`.`chat_category_images` AS `ChatCategoryImage`  WHERE `ChatCategoryImage`.`chat_category_id` = 5 ORDER BY `Frequency` DESC LIMIT 10

QUERY-2 :

SELECT `ChatCategoryImage`.`id`, `ChatCategoryImage`.`chat_category_id`,  `ChatCategoryImage`.`hits`, `ChatCategoryImage`.`created`, hits/(DATEDIFF(NOW(),created)) AS Frequency, FROM `myshowcam`.`chat_category_images` AS `ChatCategoryImage`  WHERE `ChatCategoryImage`.`chat_category_id` = 5 LIMIT 10

What is the problem and why its not coming `ORDER BY Frequency` in the second query?

Thanks
chinu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  virtualFields

```
$this->ChatCategoryImage->virtualFields = array('Frequency' => 'hits/(DATEDIFF(NOW(),created))');
```

changing the way of order

```
$order = array('Frequency' => 'desc');
```

Comment: Abhisek your code also not working. Same result coming. SELECT `ChatCategoryImage`.`id`, `ChatCategoryImage`.`chat_category_id`, `ChatCategoryImage`.`hits`, `ChatCategoryImage`.`created`, hits/(DATEDIFF(NOW(),created)) AS Frequency FROM `myshowcam`.`chat_category_images` AS `ChatCategoryImage`  WHERE `ChatCategoryImage`.`chat_category_id` = 13    LIMIT 10

Comment: can u show me code same like QUERY-2 you tried earlier. I actually tried same case as of yours and what i posted worked

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me to. You have to add to the paginate function the third parameter $whitelist. For example.

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'conditions'=>array('ChatCategoryImage.chat_category_id'=>$cetegory_id),
        'fields'=>$fields,
        'limit' => 10,
        'order' => $order,
);
$scope =  array();
$whitelist = array('ChatCategoryImage.id', ...); //The fields you want to allow ordering.

$getCategoryImages = $this->Paginator->paginate('ChatCategoryImage', $scope, $whitelist);
pr($getCategoryImages);
```

I do not know why this is happening. I tried to see the code inside the paginate function but i could not figure it out.

Comment: Nope :( its not working. By the way my `Frequency` is a alias field name. So it is not showing in the order

Answer (score -1):

Your code was lil wrong

```
    $this->paginate = array(
                   'conditions' => array('ChatCategoryImage.chat_category_id'=>$cetegory_id), 
                   'limit' => 10, 'order' => 'Frequency' => 'DESC');
    $getAllCourses = $this->paginate('ChatCategoryImage');
```

Comment: It was not  `$this->Paginator->settings` NOT  `$getAllCourses = $this->paginate('ChatCategoryImage');`